# Partycle system's labels error?

Tags: particles

I'm following this `Gleb Alexandrov` tutorial :

[Blender tutorial: How to Create a City, Covered with Fog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1ROxTnD3E0)

Go to minute 4:52,under the `particle system/render tab`,you will see that he chosen as `Dupli Group "Group.001"`. Where/when he took/created this label ? I don't have it on my side. He also has 2 others label : `g_antenna` and `group`. I imagine that `g_antenna` is related to the mesh of the antenna that he got somewhere,but I'm not able to understand where,and the other label,that's group,I don't know what is this.

I add two screens. The first is what I see on my side and the other one is what I see on the `particle system/render tab` of the Gleb Tutorial.

1)

[image: my side]

2)

[image: Gleb situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mate, Gleb created roof details meshes (antennas, chimneys and stuff) himself and grouped them to use in the particle system. You won't find them in your .blend file. You can try to find similar objects online, but if I were you, I'd just create them myself. It would be nice exercise for a beginner.

To group objects, you need to select them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. On the left bar (under <kbd>T</kbd> key) group name field will appear. You can leave the name as Group or change it to your liking. Highlight of grouped objects should turn green. Check this image to see an example:

[image: viewport look when grouping objects]

The group name will appear in particle settings.

Comment: yes. I found them online,but how can I group them using the particle system ? This is the point that I don't know how to do.

Comment: I've got the antenna,here : http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/72323 ; and the Chimney,here : http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/74699 ; and I have copied the model from the original blender file and pasted to mine,but still,I have no groups under the partycle system...